# How to group/cluster similar words

Tags: machine-learning, clustering, group-differences, pattern-recognition

Let say I have a list of words, such as:

```
apple
apale
aaple
apples
oranges
ornnges
orange
orage
melons
meeons
meeon
melon
melan
```

I want to group them based on similarity (or maybe I should say cluster them). Obviously, from above list, there are three groups: apple, orange, melon. Do you have any idea on how to achieve this (in machine learning or statistical sense)?

Thank in advance.

Comment: All you need is a simple clustering algorithm (e.g., k-means, k-means++, k-medoids/PAM, DBScan, ...) where instead of a typical distance function (euclid, manhatten, etc.) you should use a string edit distance. Did you already looked up these? https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Edit_distance

Comment: Got it. I found a better way to do this.

Comment: Let me add more information to it. As suggested, we use clustering to achieve this, which is by calculating the distance of each word. So, what I did is to use word similarity calculation by https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance, as what @roundsquare suggest :). There are also other good word similarity matrices outthere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some of what you want to do can be done via lemmatization. I've used the WordNet Lemmatizer in NLTK and is helpful. You can look at: http://textminingonline.com/dive-into-nltk-part-iv-stemming-and-lemmatization which describes it well.

Answer (score 1):

What language do you use?

If you understand Python take a look at: https://wakari.io/sharing/bundle/iuliacioroianu/Text_analysis_Python_NLTK

Answer (score 1):

Don't do this. It produces too many false matches.

```
dig
dog
fog
fag
fap
nap
```

all differ by one letter from one to the next. They would "cluster" if you do not use corpus information.